# Python Selenium wait.until(...element_to_be_clickable...) works in Firefox but not PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, integration-testing

The following line in my selenium test runs fine using Firefox but ends in a `TimeoutException` using PhantomJS:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((                           
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-icon > a"                                     
)))
```

I've tried increasing the timeout time but that doesn't help. Is there something about my syntax that would work in Firefox but not PhantomJS, or another reason this would happen?

Comment: Have you checked that you're on the correct page? Have you checked that the element is there if you simply wait a bit? Have you tried changing checking clickability to visibility?

Comment: take a screen shot just before that statement. And see if the element is visually visible to you or not ?